# GridView.DeleteRow calling 'RowDeleting' on ItemTemplate Click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hey guys I'm trying to delete a row on an itemtemplate button click, but when calling the `GridView.DeleteRow` method from within my `OnRowCommand` method, I get the error:

```
The GridView 'MyGridView' fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled
```

As far as I know, `RowDeleting` only gets called when you set the CommandName to `Delete`?

Here is a sample of my `GridView` and `OnRowCommand`:

**Gridview**

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="Gv_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
                .
                .
                .
            <asp:TemplateField>
                 <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtn" runat="server" CommandName="RemoveRow" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ImageUrl="img.png" ToolTip="Remove" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind OnRowCommand**

```
protected void Gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "RemoveRow")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                //THROWS EXCEPTION
                Gv_SelectedLineItems.DeleteRow(index);
            }
        }
```

I've been following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.deleterow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example on msdn, but haven't had any success so far. Please help.

Comment: Have you considered just handling the event with an empty handler?

Comment: So create the 'RowDeleting' handler with no body? Is that best practices?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing one thing here - Calling `Gv_SelectedLineItems.DeleteRow(index)` makes sense to expect the `RowDeleting` function.

The confusion comes from you already being inside a button callback, which a delete command sometimes also is.

When you `DeleteRow` on a `GridView`, it requires you to have this event - in the hopes you'll process anything you might need pre-deletion inside it.

Your button click - `"RemoveRow"` is irrelevant to the deletion, it's just a button click.

**Edit:**

You need to create a RowDeleting event handler. In your code-behind;

```
protected void Gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}
```

At the top of your GridView you need to add the event handler:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="Gv_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="Gv_RowDeleting">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Jono. Could you please provide a snippet or resource I could reference? I am still unclear as to how to proceed.